# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 8^kk^{2k}(\cos(1/3k)-1)^k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I study the absolute convergence of this series?

I found that the series is divergent using the root test, but idk if it can be absolutely convergent? Is that possible?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 8^kk^{2k}(\cos(1/3k)-1)^k$$

Edit: Here is the root test

$$\sqrt[k] {|8^kk^{2k}(\cos(1/3k)-1)^k|}  = |8k^{2}(\cos(1/3k)-1)|$$

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}{|8k^{2}(\cos(1/3k)-1)|}=4/9<1$$

Comment: If a series in a complete normed space (which $\mathbb{R}$ is) is absolutely convergent, then it is convergent. So the answer is no.

Comment: In the root test you should have $|\cos(1/(3k))-1|$ since $\cos(1/(3k))-1<0$ for any $k\ge 1$. Also the limit is not $\infty$ (use $\cos x = 1-x^2/2 +\mathcal{O}(x^4)$).

Comment: Yes, you are both right my mistake.

Comment: You are still missing the absolute values everywhere. You have to consider $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}$ when using the root test.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it now

Comment: It should tend to $+8/18=4/9$ and not $-8/18$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine whether the series converges absolutely or not, you have to study the convergence of:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left| 8^k k^{2k}\ \left( \cos\left(\frac{1}{3k}\right) -1\right)^k \right|$$
Now, since
$$\left| 8^k k^{2k}\ \left( \cos\left(\frac{1}{3k}\right) -1\right)^k \right|=8^k k^{2k}\  \left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{3k}\right) -1 \right|^k $$
applying the root test, as you've done, you have that
$$\sqrt[k]{8^k k^{2k}\left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{3k}\right) -1 \right|^k} \to\frac{4}{9}<1 $$
Hence the series converges absolutely.